# $P(A \mid B) + P(A \mid \bar{B}) = P(A)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm not sure if the final steps of the following proof is valid  $P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap \bar{B}) = P(A)$, and if there is anything that I need to add

To prove that the statement is true. First we use the definition of conditional probability to substitute $P(A \mid B)$ and $P(A \mid \bar{B})$. Then, we get the following for the left hand side of the equation:
$$LHS = P(A \cap B) / P(B) * P(B) + P(A \cap \bar{B}) / P(\bar{B}) * P(\bar{B})$$

which simplifies to

$$LHS = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap \bar{B})$$

Since $P(A \cap B)$ is probability of the intersection of event A and B and $P(A \cap \bar{B})$ is the intersection of event A and not B and $P(B \cap \bar{B}) = 0$ as the set of $B \cap \bar{B}$ is empty.

$$P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap \bar{B}) = P(A)$$

Therefore, LHS = RHS. The statement is true.

Comment: The statement in the _title_, viz. $$P(A\mid B) + P(A \mid B^c) = P(A)$$ is not true; and what you have done is provide a correct proof of something else:  $$P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B^c)  = P(A)$$ which could be constructed without mentioning any conditional probabilities at all.  So, what exactly is your question? Whether what you have written in the text of your question is a proof of the assertion in the title of your question?

Answer (score 2):

To show that $P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^C)=P(A)$ you can argue that since $B\cap B^C=\emptyset$ then also $(A\cap B)\cap (A\cap B^C)=\emptyset$ and so by the probability additivity axiom for disjoint sets
$$P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^C) = P((A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^C))$$
By the distributive law for sets this equals
$$P(A\cap(B\cup B^C))=P(A\cap\Omega)=P(A).$$

On the other hand the statement $P(A|B)+P(A|B^C)=P(A)$ is not correct in general because it neglects to take into account the probability of the events $B,B^C$. When you used the definition of conditional probability you should have gotten $\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} + \frac{P(A\cap B^C)}{P(B^C)}$ rather than $\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}P(B) + \frac{P(A\cap B^C)}{P(B^C)}P(B^C)$.